# Are onTouch(), onClick() running sequentially in the same thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, ui-thread

Are `onTouch()`, `onClick()`, `runOnUiThread()` running in the same UI thread sequentially? Or do I have to worry about synchronization issues among them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are onTouch(), onClick(),
>   runOnUiThread() running in the same UI
>   thread sequentially?

Yes. 99.9% of the time, Android will be calling into your methods on the main application thread. The exceptions are:

- where you are expressly telling it to use a background thread via `AsyncTask`
- if you expose an interface via AIDL to third-party apps

Comment: @Wizard: `AsyncTask` is covered many places in the documentation, such as [in its JavaDocs page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Okay but how can I possibly tell `onTouch()` to use `AsyncTask` or run in worker thread. I'm not telling about the code inside `onTouch` but the method `onTouch` itself. Is it possible to run `onTouch()` itself on a worker thread?

Comment: @Wizard: "Is it possible to run onTouch() itself on a worker thread?" -- no. My first bullet is referring to `doInBackground()` on `AsyncTask`, where you are called on a background thread.